# Reusing _kill completion in .bashrc fails

Tags: bash, process, kill, tab-completion

I'm trying to extend bash completion

```
alias perf-connect-process="perf record -p";
alias pperf=perf-connect-process;
complete -F _kill perf-connect-process;
complete -F _kill pperf;
```

by reusing the existing bash completion function `_kill`.

But when I try to complete `pperf` after reload of `.bashrc` it fails saying that function `_kill` does not exist.

However when I insert

```
complete -F _kill pperf;
```

into my bash prompt and try again things works as expected. Why?

Comment: Ok, I remove it from Stackoverflow.